# How do I modify my Laravel 5.2 registration to assign new users a role in Laravel 5.3?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I'm new to Laravel, and have been trying to build a user-role authentication system. As 5,3 is very new, there are not many resources that are beginner-friendly. I am using the authentication system created by php artisan make:auth, however I am unsure on how to associate my newly created users with a my roles table.

Initially I had been following [this video series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=21aVzSN30f8) on YouTube, but the Authentication controllers differ greatly between 5.2/5.3

I'm hoping that someone can help me figure out what must be done to add in an equivalent what is done in the video to the new controller.

**Laravel 5.2 Role Association**

```
public function postSignUp(Request $request)
{
    $user = new User();
         . . .
    $user->save();
    $user->roles()->attach(Role::where('name', 'User')->first();
}
```

**From Laravel 5.3 RegisterController.php**

```
protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
```

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the auto-generated Controllers:

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);

    $user->roles()->attach(Role::where('name', 'User')->first());

    return $user;
}
```

Comment: I wasn't aware that these could be restructured like this without breaking something. I'll give it a shot!

Comment: @FastEddysNewUsedParts As long as the method returns an instance of the `User` model, it can be safely modified.

Comment: I had to make sure to add in the usage of my model for Roles, but after that I was able to restructure the code and get this working. Thank you so much for assisting me, and helping learn a bit in the process.

Answer (score 0):

To attach a role to a user by inserting a record in the intermediate table that joins the models right after creating an account, use the attach method before returning the new User, like this:

```
/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return User
 */
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $user = User::create([
        'first_name' => $data['first_name'],
        'last_name' => $data['last_name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
    //attach default user role to user
    $user->roles()->attach(Role::where('name', 'User')->first());

    return $user;
}
```